# Route edit,show and delete not working using laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5.7

Page not found all I get when trying to get these pages.

`web.php` looks like this

```
Route::resource('admin/roles', 'RoleController');
```

`route:list` look like this

```
| GET|HEAD  | admin/roles         | index   | App\Http\Controllers\RoleController@index   
| GET|HEAD  | admin/roles/create  | create  | App\Http\Controllers\RoleController@create  
| PUT|PATCH | admin/roles/{}      | update  | App\Http\Controllers\RoleController@update  
| GET|HEAD  | admin/roles/{}      | show    | App\Http\Controllers\RoleController@show    
| DELETE    | admin/roles/{}      | destroy | App\Http\Controllers\RoleController@destroy 
| GET|HEAD  | admin/roles/{}/edit | edit    | App\Http\Controllers\RoleController@edit
```

Controllerlook like this

```
public function show($id)
{
    $role = Role::find($id);
    return view('admin.roles/show')->with('role',$role);
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $role = Role::find($id);
    return view('admin.roles.edit')->with('role',$role);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think there's something messed up with your `route:list`, since you have routes like `admin/roles/{}`. It should contain `{role}` instead of `{}` also the name should be `roles.index` etc, but then you load view `admin.roles/show`...

Answer (score 0):

You should try navigating your browser to `admin/roles/1` instead of `admin/roles/show/1`. The route you've tried doesn't exist so you're correctly getting a 404 error.

Since the create and index page work fine, but not show I think there is something up with the route bindings.

Since the routes in `route:list` command show `admin/roles/{}`, it makes me think laravel couldn't figure out the bindings.

My best guess for this it to check the http kernel. You should have the `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` middleware either in the `$middleware` array or inside the `web` group under the `$middlewareGroups` array. I suggest putting it in the `web` middleware group.

eg:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [

    //

    'web' => [
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    //
];
```

Another suggestion:

Try defining the routes individually instead of using `Route::resource()`

```
Route::get('admin/roles', 'RoleController@index');
Route::get('admin/roles/create', 'RoleController@create');
Route::patch('admin/roles/{role}', 'RoleController@update');
Route::get('admin/roles/{role}', 'RoleController@show');
Route::delete('admin/roles/{role}', 'RoleController@delete');
Route::get('admin/roles/{role}/edit', 'RoleController@edit');
```

Note you may need to add `->name('some-name')` to fix the names

Comment: Get page not found with this also. example.test/admin/roles/create works.

Comment: index page also works. Thanks for editing my post btw.

Comment: I think the clue is in the fact that index and create both work, and your `route:list` returns `admin/roles/{}` routes, instead of `admin/roles/{role}`. I've edited my answer with another suggestion

Comment: With your second suggestion show page works, but edit page still not work. Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: admin/roles/{role}] resources\views\admin\roles\edit.blade.php

Comment: SubstituteBindings are both in middlewareGroups and routeMiddleware.

Comment: It's working now. It was something with my edit.blade.php page. I had form action="{{action('RoleController@update')". It should be action="{{action('RoleController@update , $role->id')"